# I can't seem to figure out how to Login to a website and get the HTML

Tags: php, html, curl

Here is the HTML of the button

```
<form id="loginbox_form" class="okform initialized" method="post" action="https://www.okcupid.com/login">
    <div id="login_usernameContainer" class="inputcontainer input empty">
        <input id="login_username" name="username" placeholder="Your email or username"><span class="okform-feedback message empty" style="height: 0"></span>
        <div class="icon okicon"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="login_passwordContainer" class="inputcontainer input empty">
        <input id="login_password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><span class="okform-feedback message empty" style="height: 0"></span>
        <div class="icon okicon"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="sign_in_button" class="flatbutton">Let’s go</button>
</form>
```

I'm trying to make a simple script that tries to login and then gets the HTML after being logged in.

If the account information is invalid there is now this string inside the HTML

> Your info was incorrect. Try again.

Here is the code I have so far

```
<?php 
$username = 'FAKEUSERNAME';
$password = 'FAKEPASSWORD';
$loginUrl = 'http://www.okcupid.com/login';
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'login_username='.$username.'&login_password='.$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$store = curl_exec($ch);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $content;
 ?>
```

But for whatever reason, when I open up my .php page, I just get the login page of okcupid.com. I just want to be able to see if the account login failed or not.

Another idea is to try to login to a page, and then go to another page and see if that page loads. The page that you can only get to while being logged in is

> http://www.okcupid.com/profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login data should be set into cookie and read it back with the next request.

```
   curl -c cookies.txt -d "username=uname&password=yourpassword" http://site/login
```

To set cookie and in subsequent request you can use below code.

```
  curl -b cookies.txt http://site/newpage
```

In PHP, this is how you set a cookie using curl.

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookieFileName");
```

which is already done by you.

and for reading the cookie, you may use

```
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookieFileName");
```

Here is the your updated code for login

```
 <?php 
     $username = 'FAKEUSERNAME';
     $password = 'FAKEPASSWORD';
     $loginUrl = 'http://www.okcupid.com/login';
     $agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1;   .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'login_username='.$username.'&login_password='.$password);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     $store = curl_exec($ch);
     $content = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     echo $content;
   ?>
```

And, for subsequent request after login the code would look like:

```
   <?php
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.okcupid.com/afterlogin.php"); 
   $content = curl_exec ($ch);
   curl_close ($ch);
   echo $content;
   ?>
```

Make sure you have given a correct path for cookie file.

Comment: Uhh. Super stupid question, I'm not that great at cUrl, how would i change the code you provided into PHP?

Comment: Okay, super super sorry. I ran that code, and then when I FTP'd into my server, I don't see a file anywhere with cookie.txt. Also, If i want it in the same file to just check right away, would I put both of those things inside the same PHP file?

Comment: Any ideas? Not sure how to fix this